# Dimension of Injective and Surjective linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$f:V\rightarrow W$ and $dim(v) = dim(w)$. Prove that if $ker(f) =  \left\{ O \right\}$, the transformation is going to be bijective:

My answer:

If I have $ker(f) =  \left\{ O \right\}$ the transformation $f$ is going to be injective. So I just need to check for it being surjective. 
But I know that the dimensions of the domain and codomain of my transformation are the same, so every vector in the domain is going to be mapped to just one vector in the codomain, and when you do that, you cover all the domain, because their dimension is the same, that implies that this trasformation is going to be onto too, concluding, its bijective.

Am I correct?

Comment: This is in words. Now you need to convert this into mathematical notation.

Comment: In fact, this is not even a question

Comment: Thanks, i edited it and now it is haha

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Look at the [Rank-Nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: Thanks. But it's what I've concluded correct?

Comment: As written, no it's not. You didn't justify why $\mathcal R(f)=W$.

Answer (score 0):

To show this more rigorously, let bases $(v_1,\ldots, v_\ell)$ and $(w_1,\ldots,w_k)$ for $V,W$ respectively be given. Let an element $w=\sum_{n=1}^k a_nw_n\in W$ be given. Can you show that its preimage is nonempty? I.e. that $f^{-1}(w)\ne \varnothing$.

If you can, then the map is surjective. (Why?)

Obviously, the Rank-Nullity Theorem will solve your problem, but this is a good way to check your understanding of the situation.

If you need a hint: can you explain how the injective map $f$ relates the bases for $V$ and $W$?

Comment: For any vector in V, it can be described as a linear combination of the vectors in its basis. Since W has the same dimension of V, a basis for W will be the vectors in the basis V transformed. Now any vector in the domain is mapped to any vector in image, concluding that its a onto transformation. Am I correct?

Comment: That's the general idea.

Comment: Ooooh... that's nice. I'm not into math proofs that's why I write so much